# watch connectivity works on simulator but not real device, iOS9 Xcode7

Tags: watchconnectivity

My watch connectivity is working with my simulator but not my real device (iPhone and Apple watch).

I have no error messages.

Are there any settings (eg on my Xcode I needed background settings) which I need set on my devices?

Any ideas?

Thank you